# Where is the option to Enable Display Advertising Features in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

In this [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6163791?hl=en) it shows how to enable Display Advertising For Google Tag Manager. When I check my Google Tag Manager, it is no where to be found. Has Google moved this option and if so where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find it. It is under More Settings > Advertising